# Set a Default Digital Certificate

Tags: browser, ssl

We have a site that requires SSL digital certificates and have issued client side certificates to allow users to connect.  The users are now complaining that when they browse to our site they are prompted to select our certificate from a list, even though there is only one matching certificate (the one we issued).

How can the user tell their browser to always use a particular certificate (to avoid being prompted) ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a local server, give them the Root certificate to install on their browser's certificate store under **Trusted Root Authorities**. If your certificate came from a real Root CA such as [VeriSign](http://www.verisign.com/b/index.html), your customer's shouldn't need to be installing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to avoid this in Internet Explorer or Chrome but if your users use Firefox they can go to Tools, Options, Advanced, Encryption, and click "Select one automatically" under "When a server requests my personal certificate".

Answer (score 0):

In IE you have to set Internet Options >> Security >> Customer Level and set "Don't prompt for client certificate selection when only one certificate exists" to Enable.